# issue with select list not highlighting correct value in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select

I have the following class:

```
class SelectCategory extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {value: props.book.category};
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        console.log('set state handle change', event.target.value)
        this.props.onChange(this.props.book, event.target.value)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} >
                <option value="none" disabled>Move to...</option>
                <option value="currentlyReading">Currently Reading</option>
                <option value="wantToRead">Want to Read</option>
                <option value="read">Read</option>
                <option value="none">None</option>
            </select>)
    }
}
```

The issue i have is that the state changes when i select a different value, but the selected item remains the same.

[image: the console log]

[image: improper value being set]

my question is if the state is being set to the one that i want, why isnt it being reflected in the actual select element?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: May I see the parent component code ? and by the way you don't need `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)` if you already declare the function with `handleChange = (event) => { }`

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH! it was that problem! i removed the line and it works! May i ask as to why it would have been incorrect as whenever the state changed and the parent would render it again, it would be set to something new, not keeping state?

Comment: also set the state in following manner ```constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.setState ({value: props.book.category}) ;
    }```